# Этимология слова скоморох

Tags: этимология

Интересно, каково происхождение слова "скоморох"? Оно русское или тюркское?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово не имеет достоверной этимологии. По одной версии — др.-русск. *скоморохъ* (Пов. врем. лет под 1068 г.), сербск.-церк.-слав., русск.-церк.-слав. *скомрахъ*, др.-польск. *skomrośny, skomroszny* «бесстыдный, нескромный», *skowryśny, skowrośny* «веселый, живой» и т. п. — **из *sko- и* морочить***, по другой — из др.-греч.* σκώμμαρχος от σκῶμμα «шутка, проделка», однако данная форма не зафиксирована. Скоморохи часто носят "латинскую одёжу". Несмотря на это этимология слова **скоморох** из ит. sсаrаmuссiа "шут", откуда франц. sсаrаmоuсhе, англ. sсаrаmоuсh "хвастун, негодяй", не является достоверным. Нет основания говорить также о происхождении из араб.-тур. masсara "смешной человек, шут, паяц". (по словарю Фасмера).

Answer (score 0):

Вот интересное исследование по этому поводу от Александра Чашева

Почти два столетия исследователи-профессионалы и просто любители пытаются объяснить этимологию (происхождение) слова «скоморох». Существует более двух десятков версий. Вот некоторые.

```
 В 30-х годах  XIX века чешский славист П.Шафарик напомнил о кочевом народе – скамарах, живших в  V веке на Дунае, и занимавшихся разбоем и грабежами.  От них, якобы, и произошли скоморохи. Иной аргументации учёный не привёл.
```

Сторонник теории «захожести» (иностранного происхождения) скоморохов, автор работы «Старинный театр в Европе» (1870 г.)   Александр Веселовский предложил «восточную» этимологию: от арабского масхара – «шут, смешной человек».

```
Современник А.Веселовского, академик Я.Грот обратился за помощью к готскому скамари и скандинавскому скемта, имеющих значение «шутить». При этом он предположил существование подобных по звучанию и смыслу слов (возможно забытых) в славянских языках. 

А.Кирпичников и Е. Голубинский «сконструировали» из греческих слов скома – «шутка» и архо – «начальствую» сочетание  скоммаpхос, переведя его как «начальник смехотворства». Следует сказать, что в греческих словарях и других источниках подобное словообразование не встречается. 

Русский филолог-славист И. Срезневский поддержал теоретиков «захожести», «обнаружив» возможную этимологию в европейских языках: в итальянском слова скарамучча и во французском – скарамуш, с одним значением – «шут», «насмешник».  Как поменялись в слове местами согласные «м» и «р»  академик не объяснил. 

Н.Кондаков в конце XIX века предложил «русскую» версию: от слова скора – «мех». Скоромох, по его мнению, - «ряженый зверем». Та же проблема с перестановкой «м» и «р» не решена.
```

По версии российского и советского филолога, академика Императорской академии и АН СССР, создателя раскритикованного впоследствии «нового учения о языке» («яфетической теории») Н.Марра, множественное число слова скомороси (скомраси) восходит к праславянским корням, а те в свою очередь к индоевропейскому  «scomors-os». Так мог  именоваться бродячий музыкант, плясун, комедиант. А уж потом это слово могло попасть в европейские языки.

Поиски в доступных автору данной статьи словарях санскрита (В.А.Кочергиной в их числе) приведённого Н.Марром слова («scomors-os») результатов не принесли.

Шут в санскрите имеет значения (в русской транскрипции) – муддха и затха; шутка- лиила и шабал; музыкант – вена и талава; актёр – шайлуша и калажна.

Возможно, у академика были другие, недоступные нам источники.

Иных, заслуживающих внимание этимологических гипотез слова «скоморох» нет. И потому…

```
                         ЕЩЁ ОДНА ВЕРСИЯ
```

Его настоящее имя утрачено в далёком прошлом. Наши предки, говоря о нём уважительно, иногда шёпотом,  называли по разному:  «дед», «старик», «отец», «отчим», «дядя», «хозяин», «зверь», «владыка», «барин» и т.д.

```
Он – предок и родоначальник, тотем, хозяин нижнего мира, дух, охраняющий и исцеляющий. Славяне почитали его как повелителя леса, воплотившегося в божестве под именем Велес.
```

Всё это и многое другое относится к медведю.

На Руси медведь приобрёл сакральное, магическое значение. Издавна приручили его скоморохи, в потехах народных главную роль уступили.  «Он,  выученный  и  нашколенный  различным  людским ухваткам и людскому поведению, бродил со своими поводырями по  всей русской земле, из города в город, из деревни в деревню,  потешая  и забавляя  добрых  людей  карикатурным,  а  отчасти  и  сатирическим представлением их же нравов и обычаев" (И. Е. Забелин. Домашний быт русских царей, т. I, ч. II).

Популярность медвежьих игр была огромна. Русские скоморохи с косолапыми артистами в XVI веке бывали в Германии и даже в Италии.

«С медведем ходящий»  - и так можно назвать походного скомороха. От него, как «от печки» и предлагается начать обоснование ещё одной возможной этимологии слова «скоморох».

Для начала вспомним присказку «первый блин комом». Другую форму и смысл совершенно иной имело это привычное нашему слуху выражение в давние времена и  длиннее было. Неискаженная  пословица звучит так: «Первый блин комАм, блин второй – знакомым, третий блин – родне, а четвёртый – мне».

```
КомАми  наши дедичи называли медведей, прародителями их своими считали. Похожи мишки на большой мохнатый ком.
```

После долгой зимы голодными просыпались бурые комы,  надо было их уважить и задобрить, относили славяне первые, выпеченные по случаю праздника пробуждения медведя  блины  к берлогам. Праздник этот весенний назывался Комоедицей. В наши дни под именем Масленицы он известен.

С комАми ходили «весёлые люди» - скоморохи.  Кстати, во многих документах именуются они ещё и скомрАхами. В Стоглаве (1551 г.), например, читаем: «К  венчанию  бы  ко святым божиим цеpквам,  скомpахом  и  глyмнцом  пеpед  свадьбою  не ходити, а священником бы о том  запpещати  с  великим  запpещением чтобы такое бесчиние никогда же неименовалося». (Стоглав".  Изд.  Д.  Кожанчикова.  СПб.,  1863).

```
Там же в ответе на 23-й вопрос: «Всем священником, по всем гpадом и селом,  чтобы  пpавославных  хpистиан наказывали и yчили, в котоpые вpемена pодители своя поминают и  они бы нищих покоили, и милостыню бы по силе давали, и коpмили и поили, а скомpахом бы и всяким глyмником запpещали и возбpаняли, чтобы в те вpемена, коли поминают pодители, пpавославных хpистиан  не  смyщали теми бесовскими игpами».

 Какое из названий более древнее  - скоморох или скомрах? Увы, неизвестно.

От каких глаголов они образованы? Глагол «скоморошить» довольно часто встречается в старинных письменных актах. А вот «скомрашить» автору статьи пока не попадался на глаза.

  Зато в Словаре древнего славянского языка, составленного А. Старчевским по Остромирову Евангелию (С-Пт., 1899 г. стр.731) нашлось причастие РАЧЬШНН, имеющее значения «шагающий», «идущий». Кстати, в санскрите обнаружены его «близкие родственники»: слова рч и рш в этом языке имеют значение «движение».
```

К сожалению, глагол, от которого образовано причастие РАЧЬШНН, в словаре Старчевского не приводится. Можно предположить его в форме «рачьшннить». Как будет звучать существительное?

Существует глагол «ходить», от  него образовано причастие «ходящий» и существительное  «ходок». А идущий, шагающий, кто он? Идун, шагун? Не знаем таких.

```
Неисповедимы пути словесных изменений. Почему, например, есть глагол «мрачнеть», а существительные от него «мрак» и «морок»?    

Не допросить авторов и многочисленных соавторов слов и их трансформаций.

 Вспомним также глагол «ворошить» и производные от него причастие «ворошащий»,  существительное «ворох».

Может быть, в подобном алгоритме  образовано существительное от глагола «рачьшннить»? И звучать оно могло как «рах» или «рох»? Человека, профессионала, водящего медведя, можно было назвать «с комом рах». Или всё-таки более древним является выражение "с комом рш"?
```

Когда произошло образование из указанных древнеславянских (протоиндоевропейских?) элементов единого слова «скомрах» («скоморох»), "скоморош?  Возможно, в недрах русской лингвистической системы.

Comment: Лично мне более близка версия "скомороха" как "ходящего с медведем".

Answer (score 0):

"Комедия с Петрушкой разыгрывалась на ярмарках и в балаганах. Ширма петрушечника состояла из трёх рам, скреплённых скобами и затянутых ситцем. Она ставилась прямо на землю и скрывала кукольника. Шарманка собирала зрителей, а за ширмой актёр через пищик (свисток) начинал общаться с публикой. Позже, со смехом и репризой, выбегал он сам, в красном колпаке и с длинным носом. Шарманщик иногда становился партнёром Петрушки: из-за пищика речь была не всегда внятной, и он повторял фразы Петрушки, вёл диалог." (извл. https://lektsia.com/1x20f5.html)

Пространство для кукловода, выгораживаемое от зрителя ширмой, можно определить как камера / каморка / комора.

Актер в балаганных или ярмарочных представлениях, появляющийся перед зрителем в (гриме и) образе популярного кукольного персонажа, - Скоморох, т.е., сошедший к зрителю «с коморы».

И не показывает, насколько уютно будет выглядеть его кукольная камера, нет? [Дина Сабитова. Цирк в шкатулке (2007)]

Answer (score 0):

Этимология скомороха
Есть такое французское слово «скабрёзный», связанное со славянским словом скоморох.
Скабрёзный  - происходит от франц. scabreux (ж. р. scabreuse) «опасный, трудный; скабрёзный, непристойный», далее из лат. scabrosus «шероховатый, шершавый», далее из scabere «чксать, почёсывать; скоблить», далее из праиндоевр. *skab- «скоблить» [ВКС]
scabrosus – шероховатый (лат.) > scoblenij/scrjabij/scomorox – скобленый/скрябий/скоморох (слав.)(перест. b/r; редукция m/b, x/s)
Скоморох от «скрябаный», «скобленый», производное «скабрезный», иначе, непристойная шутка, анекдот.
Отсюда глаг. «скрипеть» - scriber (лат.)/grafo – скрипеть (греч.) > skribet – скрипеть (слав.)(пропуск s, редукция k/g, b/f), иначе, писать и множество сложносоставных слов, типа «графомания», «манускрипт» - написанное рукою (слав.) и др.
Преобразования иностранных слов и латинских терминов делается по методике поиска славянских слов в иностранных словах. http://www.tezan.ru/metod.htm

Answer (score 0):

А если просто  в лоб, от слова "скоромный"?
Ведь "оскоромиться" означало нарушить пост, потом перешло на нечто постыдное, чем церковь завсегда скоморошество и считала.

Answer (score -1):

На Руси праздник масленицы называли комоедицей, поэтому театральные представления во время этого праздника назывались КОМЕДИЯМИ. Здесь неясна этимология окончания РОХ. Если это слово РОК - судьба, то тогда всё слово будет означать СВЯЗАННЫЙ СУДЬБОЙ С КОМЕДИЯМИ. Чисто русское слово. А всякие комики в английском это уже производное от скомороха.

Comment: А что такое *комоядь*? И про комедию - фантазии ваши. Слово греческое.

Comment: Где доказательства Ваших слов?

Comment: комо означает: КОМУХА – вост. трясучка, лихоманка, лихорадка, гнетучка, комаха, комоха, кумаха, комошица и пр. – оттого, что она гнёт в ком. То есть комо – это болезнь, смерть.
Едица – тот, кто ест. Суффикс едиц(а) состоит из двух частей – корня –ед- и суфф. – иц(а). Последний участвует в образовании названий лиц женского пола от названий лиц мужского пола с тем же значением (медвед/иц(а), мастер/иц(а) и т.д.), то есть тот, кто ест смерть. Тогда ритуал праздника должен выражать нечто, поедающее смерть. А этот праздник и означает поедание весной долгой зимы - день весеннего солнцестояния.

Comment: Ну допустим, а как могло в греческий попасть? А насчет вашей этимологии - не трудитесь, без необходимого тут ряда значений, объяснений фонетики и прочего, она ничего общего с нацчной не имеет. Народная ("спинджачная - от "спинджак") версия, с этим - к Задорнову.

Comment: Попали также, как и другие русские слова. Что касается научности, то напомню Вам, что политика сайта: "Русский язык — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов, этимологов, и энтузиастов русского языка. Он создан и управляется вами, являясь частью сети Stack Exchange. С вами вместе мы создаем библиотеку подробных ответов на любой вопрос по русскому языку". Считайте меня энтузиастом. К тому же, я не вижу, чтобы официальные лингвисты привели доказательства этого слова из греческого. А почему не наоборот? Или официальными считаются только иностранные версии?

Comment: Не надо мне ничего напоминать. ))) Это переход на личности, да и память и меня хорошая..  А насчет "официальных" линвистов... Вы по совместительству энтузиастом-бюрократом нигде не числитесь? Нет такой должности, есть лингвисты, признающие лингвистику как науку, и есть народные, фоменки от лингвистики. И сколько бы последние себя "энтузиастами" не называли, толку от них - никакого.

Comment: Есть толк или нет, с этим я спорить не буду. Если Вы отрицаете полезность народной этимологии, то я буду Вам очень признателен, если Вы мне ответите на вопрос, что означают в русском и иностранных языках словосочетания КИП - КЕП - КОП - КАП. Если Вы на него не сможете ответить, то будем считать, что Вы не правы.

Comment: Я отрицаю полезность абсурдной этимологии, когдак созвучие выдается за доказательство. А на ваш вопрос отвечу. В "русском и иностранных" языках сочетания ничего не означают. Ни эти, ни другие. Потому что у "сочетаний" нет семантики. Она есть только у морфов. Так что я прав, а Вы можете считать что угодно. Если не ве5рите, задайте свой вопрос как положено, посмотрим, сколь вы найдете желающих на него ответить.

Comment: Ни на один мой вопрос Вы не смогли ответить. Задавать свой вопрос здесь бессмысленно, потому что, во-первых, никто не знает на него ответа, а во-вторых, считают, как и Вы, что "в "русском и иностранных" языках сочетания ничего не означают". А между тем все указанные трифонемы указывают на малую часть большого, равную по свойствам большому. Поэтому такие слова как Купидон, купец, кипа, копирка и Аль-Капоне имеют одинаковую основу. С уважением Ягуар.

Comment: А вам обязательно надо что бы на Ваши вопросы я отвечал?! Т.е. весь тот поток неконтролируемого сознания, что Вы тут изли, лично мне адресован? Я из всего этого готов принять только уважение.   Ну а если Вы пришли сюда, заранее зная, что на Ваши вопросы никто не знает ответа, то Вы явно дверью ошиблись. Этот случай называется "непризнанный гений" и проходит по медицинской части.

Comment: Но факт остаётся фактом: Вы так рьяно меня критикуете, что подразумевается, что Вы на все вопросы знаете ответ. Оказывается, это не так. Так почему бы Вам не прислушаться к тому, что говорят? Пусть даже эти версии не укладываются у Вас в голове. И давайте не будем намекать на медицинскую часть - я по отношению к Вам этого не делаю. А сами обиделись на "переход на личности".

Comment: Чтобы понять, что яйцо тухлое, не надо быть курицей. Почему Вы думаете, что у меня есть что-то к вам личное? Кроме вас тут еще есть несколько человек, раз за разом дающих восхитительные по своей неадекватности ответы. Я обычно даже не вспоминаю, кто из них что сказал, вижу глупость - даю свою оценку.  Я не знаю, ответы на все вопросы, но я в состоянии отличить ответ претендующий на серьезность от ответа шарлатана. DIXI

Comment: Я Вам уже на примере показал, что Вы не способны отличать серьёзный ответ от шарлатанства. Поэтому не надо ставить себя так высоко.

Comment: Я не собираюсь с Вами дискутировать. Если Вы считаете, что .ваш собеседник настолько глуп, что не видит очевидного, то как он может понять и оценить Ваши примеры? И зачем Вы хотите убедить в своей научной дееспособности именно такого оппонента?

Comment: Вот именно, что ни понять, ни оценить он не может, но считает, что он прав.

Comment: Комоядица - это современная Масленница, но "комАми" называли медведей. Их и подкармливали блинами в Комоядицу - "первый блин кому (а не комом как говорят сейчас)" пошло именно оттуда. Слово "рох" - это старославянское слово, кстати сохранившееся в Белорусском и украинском языках как "рух", что означает "движение". Соответственно "скоморох" - "ходящий с медведем".

Answer (score -2):

от оскомины.  оскомина--сморщенное в ком лицо(комок нервов) часто после кислого. такая же МИНА и при смехе.  А смеяться можно до упаду, до смерти.  Смешить это морока, работа такая, трудная. Соединение двух корней с несколько измененным произношением  и есть скоморох. а еще одно изменение--КОМИК--это на западе.